# How do you perform feature detection in ScriptSharp?

Tags: script#

For example, if I was coding something in JavaScript that used the `getContext` function of a canvas I would write JavaScript similar to what you see below to make sure the canvas has a `getContext` function before using it:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("SomeCanvas");
if (canvas.getContext) {
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    // Do something with the context...
}
```

What is the preferred way of doing feature detection like this using Script#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```cs
if(Type.HasMethod(canvas, "getContext")) 
{
    ...
}
```

or in general, the set of methods in `Type`.